# Reccurrence T(n) = T(n^(1/2)) + 1

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, analysis, recurrence

I've been looking at this reccurrence and wanted to check if I was taking the right approach.

```
T(n) = T(n^(1/2)) + 1
= T(n^(1/4)) + 1 + 1
= T(n^(1/8)) + 1 + 1 + 1
...
= 1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1 (a total of rad n times)
= n^(1/2)
```

So the answer would come to theta bound of n^(1/2)

Comment: [Verify it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29+%3D+T%28n%5E%281%2F2%29%29+%2B+1) with  Wolphram Alpha.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**hint:** assume n = 2<sup>2<sup>m</sup></sup> or m = log<sub>2</sub>log<sub>2</sub>n, and you know 2<sup>2<sup>m-1</sup></sup> * 2<sup>2<sup>m-1</sup></sup> = 2<sup>2<sup>m</sup></sup> so, if you define S(m)=T(n) your S will be:

> S(m) = S(m-1)+1 → S(m) = Θ(m) → S(m)=T(n) = Θ(log<sub>2</sub>log<sub>2</sub>n)

extend it for the general case.

In recursion like T(n) = T(n/2) + 1, in each iteration, we reduce the height of the tree to half. This leads to Θ(logn). In this case, however, we divide the input number by a power of two (not by two) so it turns out to be Θ(log log n ).

Comment: so this means the the height of the recurrence tree is log log n?

Comment: Yes exactly it is log log n (in base 2), in fact sqrt reduces value in power of 2 ( not two times).

Answer (score 18):

Here is how you can find the answer without any hints, just by using math.

Start unrolling the recursion: [image].

The recursion will at some point stop, so we have to find a reasonable stopping point. Trying 0, 1, 2, you can see that 2 looks good, because you can easily solve the equation: [image].

Solving it, you get [image].

So the recursion will continue `log(log(n))` times and this is your time complexity.

**P.S.** a little bit harder recurrence was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34259293/1090562).

Comment: I like to study with your answers, I hope a day I will reach >10k points thereby working with you, sir. +1

Comment: **For those** having difficulty to catch _loglogn_ part, [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwaaX.jpg) can help you.

Comment: @snr Thanks for providing the handout. Cheers!