# Recurrence Relation T(n) = T(n^(1/2)) + T(n-n^(1/2)) + n

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

My friend and I have found this problem and we cannot figure out how to solve it. Its not trivial and standard substitution method does not really work(or we cannot apply it correctly) This should be quicksort with pivots at rank problem.

Here is the recurrence:

T(n) = T(n^(1/2)) + T(n-n^(1/2)) + n

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think this belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take it easy:

T(n) = T(n-n^(1/2)) + n, number of iteration is n^(1/2), in each iteration you'll have n-k*sqrt(n) time complexity, so total time complexity is: ∑n-k*sqrt(n)  for 0<=k<=sqrt(n), which is n^(3/2).

Now solve your own problem:

```
T(n) = T(n^(1/2))+T(n-n^(1/2)) + n
```

again calculate number of steps till arriving to zero or 1: first part `T(n^(1/2)) takes O(log log n) time, and second part takes O(sqrt(n)) times to arriving to zero or 1 (See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550455/reccurrence-tn-tn1-2-1/9550494#9550494) to related question), So second part dominates first part, Also in each iteration time complexity of second part causes to sqrt(n) extra item, which doesn't effect to the first part time complexity (n-sqrt(n)), so your total runtime is n*sqrt(n).

Comment: i didnt get your point "number of iteration is n^(1/2), in each iteration you'll have n-k*sqrt(n) time complexity" can you please explain how n-k*sqrt(n) has come from relation giving 2-3 lines of iteration

Comment: should not the number of iterations be log(log n)?

Comment: @abhishekjaiswal, No.

Comment: can you please explain how? I am using this relation n^(1/(2^i)) = 2 which gives i= log (log n)

Comment: @abhishekjaiswal, Consider the first equation : T(n) = T(n-n^(1/2)) + n, it goes for sqrt(n) many steps to arrive to zero.