# Find theta of: T(n) = T(n^(1/2)) + 1

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, recurrence

I tried this for many hours and I keep arriving at log(logn) (where log is base 2) but this does not agree with Masters Theorem which maintains it would be just log(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Master's Theorem doesn't apply here, as we aren't dividing the input by a constant at each step. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In order to apply the Master Theorem, we have to be dividing by a constant at each step.  We can still use it in this case, but we have to transform the problem.

Let `k=log n`, where the logarithm is base `b`, and define `S(k)=T(b^k)`.  Then `S(k)=T(b^k)=T(n)=T(n^{1/2})+1=T((b^k)^{1/2})+1=T(b^{k/2})+1=S(k/2)+1`, and we can apply the Master theorem to `S`, which tells us that `S(k)=Theta(log k)`.  Therefore, `T(n)=T(b^{log n})=S(log n)=Theta(log(log n))`, as you found.

Answer (score 0):

People correctly suggested you that masters theorem does not work here.
To solve your problem you have to start unrolling the recursion: [image].

The recursion will at some point stop, so we have to find a reasonable stopping point. Trying 0, 1, 2, you can see that 2 looks good, because you can easily solve the equation: [image].

Solving it, you get [image].

So the recursion will continue `log(log(n))` times and this is your time complexity.

**P.S.** a little bit harder recurrence was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34259293/1090562).