# T(n)=2T(n−−√)+logn

Tags: math, logarithm, recurrence

I am trying to find the time complexity for the recurrence:

> T(n) = 2T(n<sup>1/2</sup>) + log n

I am pretty close to the solution, however, I have run into a roadblock. I need to solve:

> n<sup>(1/2<sup>k</sup>)</sup> = 1

for k to simplify my substitution pattern. I am not looking for answers to the recurrence, just a solution for `k`.

Comment: I don't think that would help. If you solve that for `k` you get something positively frightening.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question, not a programming question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you start unrolling the recursion, you get:
[image]

---

Here the same thing with a few additional steps:

### [image]

Now using the boundary condition for a recursion (number 2 selected as 0 and 1 do not make sense), you will get:

[image]

Substituting `k` back to the equation you will get:

[image]

Here are a couple of recursions that use the same idea.

- [T(n) = T(n^1/2) + 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34258332/1090562)
- [T(n) = T(n^1/2) + O(loglog(n))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149168/solve-recurrence-tn-tn1-2-%CE%98lg-lg-n/34259293#34259293)

Comment: sir , see my approach here https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2uiq.png, please help me to move forward .Thank you :)

Comment: @laura I think there are no problems in my solution. I added a few intermediary steps.

Comment: yes you are correct .Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to solve

> n<sup>(1/2<sup>k</sup>)</sup> = 1

for k, since if n > 1 then n<sup>x</sup> > 1 for any nonzero x. The only way that you could solve this is if you picked k such that 1 / 2<sup>k</sup> = 0, but that's impossible.

However, you *can* solve this:

> n<sup>(1/2<sup>k</sup>)</sup> = 2

First, take the log of both sides:

> (1 / 2<sup>k</sup>) lg n = lg 2 = 1

Next, multiply both sides by 2<sup>k</sup>:

> lg n = 2<sup>k</sup>

Finally, take the log one more time:

> lg lg n = k

Therefore, this recurrence will stop once k = lg lg n.

Although you only asked for the value of k, since it's been a full year since you asked, I thought I'd point out that you can do a variable substitution to solve this problem. Try setting k = 2<sup>n</sup>. Then k = lg n, so your recurrence is

> T(k) = 2T(k / 2) + k

This solves (using the Master Theorem) to T(k) = Θ(k log k), and using the fact that k = lg n, the overall recurrence solves to Θ(log n log log n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: sir, can i solve it like this -:T(n) = 2T(n1/2) + log n =>T(2^m)=2T(2^(m/2))+log 2^m =>T(2^m)=2T(2^(m/2))+m=>let 2^m=k=>S(k)=2S(k/2)+log k

Comment: Close! If you plug in k = 2^n, what happens to the log n term when you express it as a function of k?

Answer (score 0):

dude if it were quick sort that was the equation:

[image]

The solution for this is `O(n*log(n))` since now it is even smaller(`T(n) ~ n^1/2`) for some `N` it means your complexity is less than `O(n*log(n))`.

Try to use induction to prove your bound

Comment: Yeah, I agree it would be, as the combine is sub linear, and the input size is much smaller as well. However, if all else fails, I will try induction, but I am just curious in general how I might solve equations of the form c^a^b = 1 for b. I know it involves some trickery using power identities.

Answer (score 0):

log base anything of 1, is 0.

so

n^((1/2)^k) = 1

log(n)(n^((1/2)^k)) = log(n)(1)

1/2^k = 0

log(1/2)((1/2)^k) = log(1/2)(0)

log base anything of 0 is negative infinity.. so...

k = -infinity.

I think you should use a different "final number" for n, than 1
just saying...

Comment: mainly because you'll never be able to continue square rooting until 1.  You'll go insane.